# Coldfusion linkedin Profile API call

Tags: http, coldfusion, linkedin-api

I'm trying to invoke the below URL:

[https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,skills)?oauth2_access_token=blabla](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~%3a%28id,first-name,last-name,industry,skills%29?oauth2_access_token=blabla)

When I make the call directly from the browser it works fine, but if I call it using `cfhttp` request I got 404 Not Found error.

The issue is most likely related to url encoding, kindly advise how send the request using cfhttp or another method without being enforced to be urlencoded

Comment: You may want to take a look at a very recent blog post by Ray Camden:http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/4/3/ColdFusion-and-OAuth-Part-2--Facebook  it may further you with formatting on your calls.

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: Steve, I wish I found rymond post earlier it would saved me two hours. Unfortunatley what he posted is exactly what I developed. But when I want to retrieve specific fields from the profile I need to include something like the below in the url:

:(id,first-name,last-name,industry,skills)

This is working if I call the url from the browser but using cfhttp is making the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the cfhttp enforce encoding of the URL. I found a function on the below blog that can be used to replace the cfhttp

http://coldfusion9.blogspot.gr/2012/03/custom-cfhttp-tag.html?showComment=1366715001465#c172925816683016138